# Retrieving the Line Item of an Old Record

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I have a User Event Script that is deployed to Sales Orders. It uses the field values of line items to determine the quantity left. However, if I remove a line item it doesn't update the quantities of the removed item. I need the the item to be updated afterSubmit.

Is it possible to edit the quantities of the removed line item using `nlapiGetOldRecord()` or something of that sort?

Here's what the code looks like:

```
function afterSubmit(){
    var curRec = nlapiGetRecordId();
    var item = nlapiLoadRecord('item', curRec);
    var sold = item.getFieldValue('cust_sold');
    var quantity = item.getFieldValue('cust_quantity'); 
    var leftToSell = quantity - sold;
    item.setFieldValue('cust_lefttosell', leftToSell);

    var finalValue = item.getFieldValue('cust_lefttosell');
    var old = nlapiGetOldRecord(); // only retrieves salesorder record
    nlapiSubmitRecord(item);

}
```

**EDIT:** So it turns out I can target the line items with a simple `old.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', linenum)`. 
As Adolfo pointed out below, I can target the line item of the old record. For some reason I thought the only way to target it was by using `nlapiGetLineItemField(type, fldnm, linenum)`. The `getLineItemValue` version of the function was exactly what I was looking for.
This is what the code would look like:

```
var old = nlapiGetOldRecord();
var id = old.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', linenum);
var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('type', id);
```

Comment: You should post some examples of your code.

Comment: @opticon added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make cust_lefttosell a formula field so the value is always calculated on the fly from cust_quantity - cust_sold?

Anyways, if you want to use an afterSubmit then you have to iterate through all the line items in the old record, find out which ones were removed and then update the quantity on those.

Comment: Uncheck store value.

Comment: Accidently deleted my comment. The formula in default value would be `{cust_quantity} - {cust_sold}` and then like you said, uncheck the store value. I have also updated my post with the help from your answer. Thanks!